# Display text widget with text after clicking "About" in Help menu

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi All I have a help menu in tkinter which has `About` in the drop down menu. I want to display some text in the text widget when I click on the `About`, however when I run my current code, it doesn't display the text widget with the inserted text after I click the `About`. Below is my sample code for demonstration. Thanks in Advance.

```
menubar = Menu(root)
helpmenu = Menu(menubar)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command=help)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

info = Text(root, bd=2, wrap="word")
info.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
info.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

def help():
    info.insert(INSERT, "Designed:" + "\n")

### After I run this code, no text widget shows up with the displayed text "Designed".
### Not sure what I am missing in my code.
```

Comment: Not sure about the in's and out's of tkinter, but my first thought is that `help()` is a builtin and that your `helpmenu.add_command` might be referencing the builtin rather than your defined function that comes after?

Comment: I don't see how this code runs at all. `place` doesn't support the arguments of `side` and `fill`. Please provide a working [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley, that's a typo. Its supposed to ```pack()```

Comment: @TheLazyScripter, so you mean when I change the name of my function to another name, it will work?

Comment: Yes but you also need to move the function definition to before creating the menu.

Comment: @acw1668, yes I did that but still the text widget with the inserted text is not display.

Comment: You didn't see the *text widget* at all or just the inserted text? It is better to update your question with a [mre].